# ¿Generar números aleatorios?

Tags: java

Estoy queriendo generar numero aleatorios con `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("Comando")`,no sé que comando se pasa, para que ejecute los números aleatorios.

Comment: `exec` se usa para correr desde Java un comando externo (en tu sistema operativo, Windows, Linux o lo que sea). Por qué quieres ejecutar un comando externo para genera numeros aleatorios, cuando Java te provee esa funcionalidad con la clase Random ?

Comment: si se que existe esa funcionalidad, es por un tema de estudio.Se podria devolver un numero aleatorio mediante un jar?

Comment: Me parece que no entiendes, o yo no entiendo. Si quieres ejecutar un programa externo para generar un numero aletatorio, pues tu problema no es de programación. Esto no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 1):

El método `Runtime.exec()` se emplea para ejecutar un comando del sistema operativo, mientras que lo que tú quieres es generar números aleatorios.

En primer lugar, debes saber que los números aleatorios (es decir, al azar), no existen como tal en una computadora, pues se pueden generar números con un algoritmo, pero no al azar, pues ningún algoritmo puede generar resultados aleatorios (se pueden generar resultados determinados a partir de una entrada).

Muchos lenguajes de programación incluyen, por ello, un generador de números pseudoaleatorios. Para este objetivo, emplean algún derivado del [generador de números aleatorios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_pseudoaleatorio), que trata de garantizar que los resultados de este generador sigan una distribución normal (es decir, que gráficamente, sigan una campana de Gauss).

Una forma de obtener resultados distintos con cada ejecución del programa es utilizar una semilla basada en el reloj del ordenador, que siempre cambia (**hacia adelante**).

En Java, tienes la clase [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) para generar números de este tipo.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Alea {
    public static void main()
    {
        // Crear un generador aleatorio, basado en el reloj
        Random rnd = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );

        // Visualiza un número dentro del rango: [0, 100)
        System.out.println( rnd.nextInt( 100 ) );
    }
}
```

Espero que este te ayude.